# Java - JavaPlot under Mac OS X 10.8 - Could I somehow avoid installing gnuplot?

Tags: java, gnuplot, portability, javaplot

If you don't know JavaPlot, it's a Java library which 'connects' Java with the popular gnuplot providing a set of classes. When it runs, it searches for the gnuplot binary in your system. Anyway, some months ago I've been through the awful experience of installing gnuplot under Mac OS and now all my data are gone, so gnuplot is not on my system anymore.

In order to avoid installing it again, and in order to improve portability for my Java applications, is there someway to embed the raw just-as-when-downloaded gnuplot folder into my Java project and tell JavaPlot to look for the binaries in that folder?

You know, it would make my applications work on every kind of OS even if gnuplot is not installed.

Thank you in advance,

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, `JavaPlot` is a pipe based interface to gnuplot.  If that's true, you can't really get around having `gnuplot` installed somewhere that Java can find it.  That said, I've never had any problems with `gnuplot` on OS-X -- and I've built it from source a number of times ...

Comment: I know I could build gnuplot from source, but I still have problems in compiling projects from source. Anyway, the major issue is still portability: I would like to have a final application, entirely written in Java, which could run on any OS (at least Unix ones, hopefully Windows too).

Comment: @whatyouhide -- Then you'll probably need to move away from `JavaPlot` or have a properly installed `gnuplot` as a system requirement.